# Execute another query for every record fetched in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Nodejs (12.14.1 LTS) & mongoose (5.8.11)
Consider the following collections

```
collection1: {  
  // collection1 fields  
  rank_type : "some_value", 
  col1_price : "some_value",  
  col1_location : "some_value"   
}

collection2 : {  
  // collection2 fields  
  price : "some_value",  
  location: "some_value"  
}
```

I need the following things to do in single query
1. Fetch records from collection1 on basis of some condition
2. On every record fetched in first step need to fetch records from collection2

```
// explained in sudo code or some simplified way  
fetch from collection1 on basis of some condition {  
    loop on documents fetched from collection1 (docN) {  
      if(docN.rank_type === "high"){
         fetch documents from collection2 with conditions ( price : docN.col1_price, location:docN.col1_location)  
      } else if(docN.rank_type === "medium"){
         fetch documents from collection2 with some other conditions ( price : docN.col1_price, location:docN.col1_location, more_conditions_will_be_there)
      }
    }  
}
```

I want output in below fashion

```
[
  {
    col1_id : _id_from_col1_document
    matched_details : [
      {document_from_col2},
      {document_from_col2}...
    ] 
  },
  ... other_records
]
```

What I tried is

```
var cursor = collection1.find(some_condition).cursor();
cursor.on("data", doc => {
   if(doc.rank_type === "high"){
      collection2.find(some_conditions).then(result_documents =>{
         // did some loging
      })
   } if(docN.rank_type === "medium"){
      collection2.find(some_other_conditions).then(result_documents =>{
         // did some loging
      })
   }
});
```

In the above code I am not able to understand when the operation is finished and how to get desired output mentioned above.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @goto1 I have updated the question, I have also added some more details in original collection structure and sudo code.